# XStream serializing collections

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

I have a class structure that I would like to serialize with Xstream. The root class contains a collection of other objects (of varying types). I would like to only serialize part of the objects that are stored in the collection (primarily their IDs, and not the remaining contents of each element).

Anyone have an idea of how I might go about this?

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify that all the collection element fields except for ID [should not be serialized](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Serialization) by either:

1. Declaring them `transient`
2. Annotating them with [@XStreamOmitField](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/annotations/XStreamOmitField.html)
3. Calling [xstream.omitField()](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#omitField(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

Or you can [write your own converter](http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html).

Comment: writing your own converter is actually pretty simple, so don't overlook that option if for some reason the others ones aren't feasible for you.