# XStream avoid collection xml element

Tags: java, collections, xstream

Given a `List` of POJO's, if I serialize them with XStream I get:

```
<list>
  <pojo>
     <a>a</a>
     <b>b</b>
  </pojo>
  <pojo>
     <a>a</a>
     <b>b</b>
  </pojo>
</list>
```

How can I do the serialization and omit the `<list> </list>` entries?  I've used `addImplicitCollection` for a similar purpose but that was to omit the collection instance variable *name* when the collection was a member of a class being serialized.

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730314/xstream-serializing-collections) question appears similar but not exactly relevant (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Imagine that `<list>` node was gone - how would XStream know how to deserialize this XML? It can be list / set / array / something else entirely. Furthermore, imagine you have an object containing a list of your `pojo` followed by a single `pojo` field - they'd be jumbled together.

That said, if you have no intention of deserializing this, you can implement your own stream driver and writer akin to [JSON writer](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html) that would drop the `<list>` for you.

Comment: This is not true any longer, see answer below.

Answer (score 4):

These days (using XStream 1.4.1) it is possible to omit the container element from the output using "[implicit collections](http://x-stream.github.io/manual-tweaking-output.html#Configuration_ImplicitCollection)"

Answer (score 1):

XML must have a single root element, so ChssPly76 is right, but of course if you are streaming XML then you can just write each pojo one after the other (make sense from a memory perspective as well).

See http://x-stream.github.io/objectstream.html for details.